# Reuse function result in shorthand if statement

Tags: php, function, ternary-operator

Is there a way, without declaring a variable to hold the function's result, to use the result of the function called in a shorthand if statement, like:

```
!empty(getType($user)) ? <RESULT OF FUNCTION> : ''
```

Rather than doing:

```
!empty(getType($user)) ? getType($user) : ''
```

Which effectively calls the function twice.

Comment: What does `getType` return? Does it really require `!empty`, which is mostly alike a plain boolean test there? Else just go for `getType() ?: ""` even.

Comment: @mario See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php :)

Comment: @Rizier123 I thought it's just an example. A plain PHP `gettype()` wouldn't ever return anything other than a stringy/truthy result.

Comment: @mario gotcha. Yeah could probably be.

Comment: @mario `getType()` was just an example, but in my code the function returns a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply assign the return value of your function to a variable, e.g.

```
!empty($result = getType($user)) ? $result : ''
     //^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^ See here
```

**EDIT:**

Since [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) always returns a string, you can just do the following, but then the ternary wouldn't make sense, since it always returns a string.

```
getType($user)?: ''
```

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly, but

```
php > echo (empty($foo = 0)) ? $foo : 'false';
0
```

Since the result of an assignment operation in PHP is the value being assigned, you get $foo defined, then can use it later for the `true` clause.